# Where to put graphql mutations in Sails?

Tags: sails.js, graphql, sails-postgresql

I've installed npm sails-graphql, but I dont know where to put a mutation, surfing on the web I've found nodejs examples in which they add mutations in index.js but in sails there are no such file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sails-graphql adapter creates a schema automatically with mutations for all models in `/api/models` if its specified in the controller:

```
        // api/controllers/GraphQLController.js
        var graphql = require("graphql");
        var sailsGraphQL = require("sails-graphql");
        ...
        if (!schema) {
        schema = sailsGraphQL.generateSchema(sails.models);
        }
        ...
```

In this case there is no need to manually add mutations.
See https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-graphql#usage

Although if you want to edit the generated schema, a better option would be to use a graphql implementation for the required language and load the mutations manually.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for best way to organize SailsJS + GraphQL app, and trying out multiple variants, the best one and the one we decided to use was to create a `graphql` folder, and inside of it create a folder for each entity in our app's model. We stored the queries and mutations, type and utils for the entity inside the entity folder.

[Here](https://kolosek.com/sails-graphql-guide/) you can take a look at how the structure of the app looks like in full, including how the tests are organized.